# php regex to select a string based on a start string until space but exclude select string

Tags: php, regex

Supposing we have a string like:

```
text text MinorAlleleCount:G=0.4627/56166 text text text
```

I am using this regex:

```
/(MinorAlleleCount)[^\s]+/
```

Which returns:

```
MinorAlleleCount:G=0.4627/56166
```

But I would like it to exclude the (MinorAlleleCount) pattern so as to return:

```
G=0.4627/56166
```

Can this be done without resorting to a **substr()**?

Comment: Use a [positive lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Expression

You can use this regex to have your match:

```
MinorAlleleCount:\K\S+
```

It performs the same job as with a positive lookbehind, but in far less steps.

[See the demo](https://regex101.com/r/irz4NS/2)

If you want to make sure that `MinorAlleleCount:` doesn't start in a middle of a word, like in `SomethingMinorAlleleCount`, you can add a word boundary (`\b`) at the beginning like this:

```
\bMinorAlleleCount:\K\S+
```

#### Example

```
$re = '/MinorAlleleCount:\K\S+/';
$str = 'text text SomeMinorAlleleCount:G=0.4627/56166 text text text';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

`$matches` will contain `G=0.4627/56166`

Answer (score 1):

Try [this](https://regex101.com/r/cFqnlR/1):

```
(?<=MinorAlleleCount:)\S+
```

`(?<=)` positive look behind
`\S+` one or more not whitespace